# Adding dropdowns to all cells in a column in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I did a tutorial to make drop down lists in cells and came up with this code...

```
Sub test()
    AddYesNoDropdown ("H5")
End Sub

Public Function AddYesNoDropdown(r)
    With Range(r).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes, No"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = False
        .ShowError = False
    End With
End Function
```

I need to do it in every cell within a named table (ListObject?) referencing the column by name and not index in case the table column were to get moved or renamed etc.

I have tried searching the internet and tried myself but I don't know where to start. Once I start trying to do stuff in a table it gets confusing...for example...

Having to do...

```
.ListColumns("Expected Ship Date?").Range.ColumnWidth = 10.14
```

Instead of...

```
.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 10.14
```

I know this is probably simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it thus, using Match to find the relevant column and then passing that column of the table to your function (as a range). So this would add DV to every cell in that column.

```
Sub test()

Dim v As Variant

With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    v = Application.Match("Heading 2", .HeaderRowRange, 0) 'in my example returns 2
    If IsNumeric(v) Then AddYesNoDropdown .ListColumns(v).DataBodyRange
End With

End Sub

Public Function AddYesNoDropdown(r As Range)
    With r.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes, No"
        .IgnoreBlank = False
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = False
        .ShowError = False
    End With

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I'm sure this isn't the last of the trouble I'll have referencing ListObjects...

Comment: Glad it worked. There is a good guide here https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables